# Как программно узнать, активен ли пользователь в ОС Windows

Tags: c#, windows

У меня есть сетевая программа, созданная на C#, в котором клиент автоматически подключается к серверу и на сервере он вносится в базу данных. Однако, есть проблема: к примеру, если на компьютере более одной учётной записи (Администратор, Гость, Юзер и т.д.) то подключается помимо активных учётных записей неактивные(если они ранее были активными), в итоге, при выполнении какого-то запроса в сторону такого пользователя, программа рушится или работает неправильно.

```
private static void BeginAsyncConnect(Object obj) {
    if (isConnected == true)
        return;
    Disconnect("Превышено время ожидания");
    IPAddress ip = (IPAddress)obj;
    Console.WriteLine(ip.ToString());
    try {
        Tcp_Client.Connect(ip, _serverPort);
        Console.WriteLine("Подключение было завершено успешно");
        isConnected = true;
        ipString = ip.ToString();
    } catch { Console.WriteLine("Невозможно установить соединение"); }
}
```

Вот код самого подключения, но думаю суть не в этом. Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы эта часть кода не выполнялась, если пользователь не активен, а программа работает

Comment: Покажите код, с которым возникла проблема.

Comment: Код скинул выше

Comment: субд какая? сделайте авторизацию в бд по учётным данным ОС

Comment: А вылетает на чём? На Connect или на WriteLine?

Comment: я так делал. у юзера есть поле онлайн. при запуске делается запрос и менятся на статус   {online: true} а когда закрывается то на  {online: false}